# Blurry web graphics on smart phone - double image size or resolution?

Tags: android, css, graphics, resolution

Various web graphics I've created are blurred on high resolution smart phone screens, unlike desktops screens.

Do I need to:

1. double the image size and programmatically resize it to half
2. increase the resolution (e.g. 72 to 300).

My understanding is that the latter only affects print rather than digital screens.

Are others experiencing this issue and if so, what it is the recommended work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. You need to double the image size, maybe even a little more if you wanted to get picky as some screen resolutions have 3x or more pixel density than a desktop monitor. Double works pretty well though so I would start there.

Resolution, as in DPI, won't do anything for web graphics on screens besides make the image resource's filesize larger than it needs to be. You could have a resolution of 5 DPI and they would look the same as 300 DPI on a screen. The main issue with lowering DPI for web graphics is when a user wants to print your page, then any images with really low DPI would be very pixelated.

Depending on the graphics you've created you have some options besides your standard image formats. You can use SVG or create your own icon font. Both are vector images so they will look sharp on any device that supports them. Icon fonts are widely supported and SVG is decent but might need a small shim depending on what you need to do.

Comment: Regarding print DPI (for printing from web as you described), is the conventional 72DPI appropriate and would you consider it optimal in terms of file size?

Comment: I would leave it there for now. Ultimately it's up to you, the purpose of your image resources and the needs of your user base (will they be printing your page because of the image resource?). If the image resources are important to the content and you have a great image then you might care more what the DPI is as the user might be printing the page for the data and image reference. Though you can always provide a link to a higher resolution image than the one supplied in the page itself.

Comment: No, nothing out off the ordinary. I'm basing my question on the general/average/ordinary requirements of a website. Thanks for you insights. You've saved me unduly increasing my file size by superstitiously producing images at 300 - 500 DPI.

Comment: No problem. The simplest thing to do is print a page with an image resource and see if you're happy with the current DPI.

Answer (score 1):

Double image size.

You should even render image (simple or doubled), depending on the device/viewport resolution.

*increasing resolution is quite a complicated matter. Print/digital/dpi/ppi; it could work on a bunch of devices but not all.*

Comment: Thank for your concise and prompt answer (+1). I derived slightly more value from the selected answer.